# Is ddrescue actually doing anything here?

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm trying to do recovery of a suddenly failed 1TB hard drive. I ran ddrescue in two sessions. The first command was

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ddrescue -f /dev/sdb /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/17BE6E9E17BE6E9E/ddr.log
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:    756 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:   702021 kB,   errors:     837,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:   702021 kB, run time:   28.16 m,  successful read:   28.16 m ago
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 3 (forwards)^C
Interrupted by user
```

and I decided to stop and do some more reading, because of the "rescued: 0 B". The output of the log file at this point was

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -f /dev/sdb /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/17BE6E9E17BE6E9E/ddr.log
# Start time:   2016-08-15 06:32:00
# Current time: 2016-08-15 07:00:09
# Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 3 (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status
0x29D80000     ?
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x29D80000  *
0x29D80000  0x00BA0000  ?
0x2A920000  0x00010000  *
0x2A930000  0x00800000  ?
[many similar lines...]
0xF6E00000  0x00010000  *
0xF6E10000  0x00010000  ?
0xF6E20000  0x0000BC00  *
```

I read some more and decided to run longer (the source drive is different, but this is not incorrect/accidental):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ddrescue -f -d /dev/sdc /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/17BE6E9E17BE6E9E/ddr.log
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from logfile)
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:    756 MB,  errors:     837

Current status
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:   4142 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:   275847 kB,   errors:       1,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:   275847 kB, run time:    7.87 h,  successful read:    7.87 h ago
Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)^C        
Interrupted by user
```

with the log after this command being

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -f -d /dev/sdc /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/17BE6E9E17BE6E9E/ddr.log
# Start time:   2016-08-20 02:07:27
# Current time: 2016-08-20 10:00:05
# Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status
0x10711A00     /
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x10711A00  -
0x10711A00  0xE671A000  /
0xF6E2BA00  0x00000200  -
```

I noticed that the drive appeared to be much much smaller than 1TB

```
/0/2/0.0.0               /dev/sdc         disk        4142MB ST1000DM003
```

though it did not sound to be making unusual noises while running (but on receiving power [yes](https://clyp.it/o0lm5r5a)). Is this drive confirmed dead? I find it odd that the drive and model would still be recognized.

Comment: If it's in an external enclosure you might try hooking it up directly; but if it's not even detected with correct capacity it's a lost cause. ST?000DM00? is known for high failure rates...

Comment: I suggest you try scalpel